# ¿Cómo implementar un controlador de AngularJS para cambiar dinámicamente un templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs

Algo como esto, pero que en vez de buscar archivos `.json` para insertarlo en el `templateUrl` con id, que busque archivos `.html` para cambiar el `templateUrl` con id dinámicamente. Estoy utilizando AngularJS 1.5.3

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers',[]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phone = data;
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que planteas, los controllers no cambian template, ni siquiera es su resposabilidad. A lo sumo podria ser en el routeProvider cuando se ingresa a una url que resuelva de forma dinamica que template y cual controller asociar, es alli donde resuelves el routing no en el controller

Comment: Saludos @LeandroTuttini entiendo lo que me explicas, te agradecería mucho si me explicaras cómo implementar algo así, estoy creando una aplicación web de noticias y cada vez que publique una noticia tendría que estar colocando cada templateUrl, quisiera tener un solo .when('/news/:id') que cambie el template automáticamente.

Comment: @AdrianoJsoué ¿Porque necesitas un nuevo fichero html para cada noticia? A menos que estos sean generados dinamicamente en el servidor despues que cada noticia sea publicada no tiene mucho sentido lo que intentas hacer. Por lo general las rutas en angular pueden cambiar de template pero esto se hace de manera discreta para seleccionar entre un conjunto disponible de "plantillas". De lo contrario se usa el *binding* con **una sola plantilla** para mostrar diferentes contenidos. Explica mejor tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Podés usar una función dentro del templateUrl que devuelva una nueva url, o que seleccione dentro de una lista.

```
when('/phones/:id', {
  templateUrl: function(params) {
    // resulta en 'partials/phonetemplate5.html' o 'partials/phonetemplate10.html'
    return 'partials/phonetemplate' + params.id + '.html';
  },
  controller: 'controller'
});
```

Te dejo un ejemplo para que lo puedas ver funcionando

https://plnkr.co/edit/OKr4Fx1rBCxcJcfOiUd5

Comment: Gracias por responder, algo así es lo que quiero implementar pero no quiero tener que estar colocando cada url ahí, estoy creando una aplicación web de noticias y cada vez que publique una noticia tendría que estar colocando cada url, hay alguna forma de que busque la url automáticamente cogiendo el id de mi ng-repeat que busca el contenido de un json ?

Comment: Adriano, buenas, ahí realicé algunas modificaciones al ejemplo, en el mismo podrás ver que los id los está tomando de un archivo externo, solo deberías tener una propiedad dentro de tu json que indique el nombre de la página del template. Cualquier consulta, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: @AdrianoJsoué pero se supone que la noticia tiene un id o codigo que lo identifica, la url seria una sola y el template que define el marco para la noticia tambien, lo que cambia es el parametro el cual usaras para recuperar el texto y mostrarlo. No tiene que definir una url por cada noticia

Comment: Adriano, lo que te comentan es verdad, hay muchas mejores formas dentro de angular de conseguir un resultado similar y mas fácil de mantener.